# Android Sqlite and or confusion

Tags: android, sqlite

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE x<y AND  z > m
OR  z<m and j=y
AND p = 1
```

Here, from my lines you can understand that, i want

1 -`x<y z>m` and `p=1` together or

2- `z<m j=y` and again `p=1`

I want one of those two lines. p=1 will be always there

but in android it gives wrong outputs.

Maybe it thinks those 2 possibilites

1-xm j=y p=1
2-x

For this, i made in parenthieses or

```
(OR  k=p and j=y)
```

But still same.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

use parentheses to help you organize the conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (x<y AND  z > m AND p = 1) 
OR (z < m AND j = y AND p = 1)
```

you can also do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE (
       (x<y AND  z > m)
        OR  (z < m and j=y)
       )
AND p = 1
```